# Permission denied on Cygnus conf/

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Already I get my Cygnus last version installed, but when I try to create my agent configuration with this order:

```
sudo cat > /usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_1.conf
```

I get always the following error

```
-bash: cygnus_instance_1.conf: Permission denied
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain how do you try to create the filel (i.e. which bash command), please? Thx!

Comment: Ok! I edit my question, I put the order that I execute.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not with FIWARE Cygnus. Try creating the file in the local directory with:

```
cat > cygnus_instance_1.conf
```

After that, verify if `/usr/cygnus/conf` really exists. In positive case, move you `cygnus_instance_1.conf` file created to the specific directory:

```
sudo mv cygnus_instance_1.conf /usr/cygnus/conf/.
```

Now you have `/usr/cygnus/conf` file in the directory you want. If you need to edit it, just use some text editor (vi, vim, nano...) with `sudo` and it will work.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Dalton!
I followed your instruction and I was able to solve my problem.

Thank you so much!!!